# Create a new systemd service via a rpm

Tags: service, rpm

I would like to install a new service on a RedHat8 machine via an RPM.
I have a service file (e.g. toto.service) and I want to copy it on /etc/systemd/system and then enable it.

But I have the following error during the installation of the rpm:
**Failed to enable unit: Unit file toto.service does not exist.**

Can you help me ?

See below an example of my .spec file

```
%define install_dir        /etc/systemd/system
%define service            toto.service


# ----------------------------------------------------------
%install
# ----------------------------------------------------------
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/%{install_dir}
cp %{service} %{buildroot}/%{install_dir}


# ----------------------------------------------------------
%files
# ----------------------------------------------------------
%defattr(0770,root,users,0770)
%{install_dir}/%{service}



# ----------------------------------------------------------
%pre
# ----------------------------------------------------------
echo "Installing %{summary} (%{version}-%{release})..."
# Enable and start the service now
systemctl enable %{service} --now



# ----------------------------------------------------------
%postun
# ----------------------------------------------------------
echo "Uninstalling %{summary} (%{version}-%{release})..."

# in case of uninstall
if [ $1 == 0 ] ; then
    systemctl disable --now %{service}
    rm %{install_dir}/%{service}
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong on many levels. Please follow these guidelines:

- https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Systemd/#packaging
- https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/#_systemd